# Red and blue colors are swapped in Android

Tags: android, colors, android-ndk

Doing an example from Sylvain Ratabouil Android NDK (2nd Edition) that gets image previews from the camera and processes it natively, converting from YUV to RGB and applying a color filter to it.

The code is very simple and the issue occurs in the filter that is passed to this function:

```
public native void decode(Bitmap target, byte[] source, int filter);
```

**target** is a reference to a ImageView
**source** is the frame preview data
**filter** is the color filter

When the code is like this:

```
decode(mImageRed,   data, 0xFFFF0000);
decode(mImageGreen, data, 0xFF00FF00);
decode(mImageBlue,  data, 0xFF0000FF);
```

The bitmaps are displayed with red and blue color swapped, no problem with green.

When I swap the red and blue color filters like this:

```
decode(mImageRed,   data, 0xFF0000FF);
decode(mImageGreen, data, 0xFF00FF00);
decode(mImageBlue,  data, 0xFFFF0000);
```

*changing **0xFF0000FF** filter with **0xFFFF0000** for the red image and vice-versa.

In the native part, what it does is just apply the filter with the bitwise operator and (&):

```
bitmapContent[yIndex] &= pFilter;
```

Does anyone knows while the colors are swapped? Because I thought that 0xFFFF0000 was red and not 0xFF0000FF.

Here is the decode function:

```
void JNICALL
decode(JNIEnv *pEnv, jclass pClass, jobject pTarget, jbyteArray pSource, jint pFilter) {

    // Retrieves bitmap information and locks it for drawing.
    AndroidBitmapInfo bitmapInfo;
    uint32_t *bitmapContent;

    if (AndroidBitmap_getInfo(pEnv, pTarget, &bitmapInfo) < 0)
        abort();

    if (bitmapInfo.format != ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888)
        abort();

    if (AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(pEnv, pTarget, (void **) &bitmapContent) < 0)
        abort();

    // Accesses source array data.
    jbyte *source = (*pEnv)->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(pEnv, pSource, 0);
    if (source == NULL)
        abort();

    int32_t frameSize = bitmapInfo.width * bitmapInfo.height;
    int32_t yIndex, uvIndex, x, y;
    int32_t colorY, colorU, colorV;
    int32_t colorR, colorG, colorB;
    int32_t y1192;

    // Processes each pixel and converts YUV to RGB color.
    // Algorithm originates from the Ketai open source project.
    // See http://ketai.googlecode.com/.
    for (y = 0, yIndex = 0; y < bitmapInfo.height; y++) {
        colorU = 0;
        colorV = 0;
        // Y is divided by 2 because UVs are subsampled vertically.
        // This means that two consecutives iterations refer to the
        // same UV line (e.g when Y=0 and Y=1).
        uvIndex = frameSize + (y >> 1) * bitmapInfo.width;
        for (x = 0; x < bitmapInfo.width; x++, yIndex++) {
            // Retrieves YUV components. UVs are subsampled
            // horizontally too, hence %2 (1 UV for 2 Y).
            colorY = max(toInt(source[yIndex]) - 16, 0);
            if (!(x % 2)) {
                colorV = toInt(source[uvIndex++]) - 128;
                colorU = toInt(source[uvIndex++]) - 128;
            }
            // Computes R, G and B from Y, U and V.
            y1192 = 1192 * colorY;
            colorR = (y1192 + 1634 * colorV);
            colorG = (y1192 - 833 * colorV - 400 * colorU);
            colorB = (y1192 + 2066 * colorU);

            colorR = clamp(colorR, 0, 262143);
            colorG = clamp(colorG, 0, 262143);
            colorB = clamp(colorB, 0, 262143);

            // Combines R, G, B and A into the final pixel color.
            bitmapContent[yIndex] = color(colorR, colorG, colorB);
            bitmapContent[yIndex] &= pFilter;
        }
    }

    (*pEnv)->ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(pEnv, pSource, source, 0);
    if (AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(pEnv, pTarget) < 0)
        abort();
}
```

And here how the bitmaps are allocated:

```
mImageR = Bitmap.createBitmap(size.width, size.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
mImageG = Bitmap.createBitmap(size.width, size.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
mImageB = Bitmap.createBitmap(size.width, size.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
mImageViewR.setImageBitmap(mImageR);
mImageViewG.setImageBitmap(mImageG);
mImageViewB.setImageBitmap(mImageB);
```

Comment: Make sure the error do not lies in the code where you are displaying those images, coz otherwise, this part of code looks fine to me.

Comment: Are you using OpenCV by any chance (as it uses BGR by default) ?

Comment: I edited the question to post de native code.

Comment: @ZeekHuge I reviewed the decode code and it seems fine for me too, it's from the book and is also based on the Ketai open source project

Comment: @AKarthik10 It doesn't use the OpenCV, it's a standalone solution that doesn't use any lib to decode the images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `decode()` function is hardcoded for NV21 video format, but the camera could be set for [YV12](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#YV12). This could account for color 'swap'. Note that for some resolutions, YV12 can have line padding (NV21 is guaranteed to be 'fully packed').

**PS** it may be significantly faster to generate the three planes in one run and it is not clear if integer operations are really faster than float on the modern CPUs.

If the resolution is high, and the processing time is important, consider using renderscript.

Comment: Great! My phone uses YV12 as default.
And thanks for the tip to improve the performance.